# How can I change the timezone in which a cron job is executed?

Tags: 20.04, bash, scripts, cron

I want to change the timezone in which the cron jobs are executed but keep the rest of the system's default timezone. Is this possible?

I read this article
https://linuxhint.com/set-timezone-crontab/

but I think this doesn't affect when the job is executed. It just specifies which timezone should be used by the process once launched by cron

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why can't  you edit the crontab and change the times there?

Comment: I can't. It's hard to give you context for that. My task is to change the cron jobs timezone.

Comment: I think you can use ```CRON_TZ```. but I don't think you can change TZ on individual entries.

Comment: Which do you mean? Change the time at which a `cron` job runs (edit the `crontab`) OR convince the `cron` job it's being run before a deadline (edit the `crontab`, set `TZ=` for the job)? Read `man -a crontab`.

Answer (score 4):

CRON_TZ instructs your cron table to run in the assigned timezone, you can also use TZ, which sets the timezone for your command if you want it to use a timezone different from the system.

```
# min hour dom month dow command
CRON_TZ=Europe/Helsinki
0 9 * * * TZ=Europe/Helsinki /bin/sh -c 'date +"$USER: \%a \%e \%b \%Y \%H:\%M:\%S \%Z"' >> /tmp/timestamp.log
```

This cron will run when the clock strikes 09:00 in Finland, i.e., 08:00 here.

```
[bac0n@betazoid ~ 07:59]: tail -f /tmp/timestamp.log
bac0n: Sat  4 Dec 2021 09:00:01 EET
```

If you want to run specific scripts in different time zones, you can use `systemd.timer` instead. There are endless ways to organize your timer/services, e.g., you can use an instantiated timer to add the different time zones.

```
# file: timezone@.timer
[Unit]  
Description=Timer for timezone %I  
  
[Timer]  
AccuracySec=1s  
OnCalendar=*-*-* 09:00:00 %I  
  
[Install]  
WantedBy=timers.target
```

The second service template is a general service for all enabled time zones, there is also possible to create a specific service for a time zone with different sets of properties.

```
# file: timezone@.service
[Unit]
Description=Service for timezone %I

[Service]
Environment=TZ=%I
ExecStart=/bin/date +"%I: %%a %%e %%b %%Y %%H:%%M:%%S %%Z"
StandardOutput=append:/tmp/timestamp.log
```

Now you can start adding your time zones.

```
systemctl enable --now 'timezone@Europe\x2fLondon.timer' 'timezone@Europe\x2fStockholm.timer' 'timezone@Europe\x2fHelsinki.timer'
```